# How to change the LSTMCell weight format from tensorflow to tf.keras

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

I I have some old code from tensorflow that I want to make work for tensorflow2/tf.keras. I would like to keep the same LSTM weights, but cannot figure out how to convert the format.

I have the old weights saved in a checkpoint file, and also have them saved in csv files.

My old code looks something like this:

```
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, input_units])
lstm_layers = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(layer_size), tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(layer_size)]
stacked = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_layers)
features, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked, input_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)
```

And my new code looks something like this:

```
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, input_units])
lstm_layers = [tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(layer_size),tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(layer_size)]
stacked = tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells(lstm_layers)
features = stacked(input_placeholder)
... #later in the code
features.set_weights(previous_weights)
```

The old bias seems to match the new bias.
The old kernel seems to be the concatenation of the kernel and recurrent kernel.
I am able to load the previous_weights into the model (have explicitly checked the weights loaded correctly), however tests I have fail to produce the same result.
Digging into the source code, the kernels seem to have a different format under the hood.

Is it possible to calculate the kernel and recurrent_kernel (tf.keras) using these old saved kernel weights?

Links if they're helpful:

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py

https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.13/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone else encounters this.

There are three differences that I found for migrating weights:

1. The kernel is shuffled in axis=0. Both implementations use one (or two) dot-products to do four dot-product operations that the lstm calls for by concatenating weights in axis=0. The challenge is that the middle two quarters of this concatenated weight matrix are swapped.
2. The kernel is divided in axis=1. The `rnn_cell` implementation has a single weights matrix that is dot-producted with a concatenation of the inputs and the hidden state, where as the `keras` implementation stores these as two attributes: `_kernel` and `_recurrent_kernel`, and dot-products these separately before summing them.
3. A forget bias is explicitly added in the cell calculation from `rnn_cell`, but is integrated into the cell bias in `keras`, with the option modifying the initialisation only.

A migration function that accounts for these three differences is

```py
def convert_lstm_weights(tf1_kernel, tf1_bias, forget_bias=True):
    a, b, c, d = tf.split(tf1_kernel, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=1)
    lstm_kernel = tf.concat(values=[a, c, b, d], axis=1)
    kernel, recurrent_kernel = lstm_kernel[:-hps.hidden_dim], lstm_kernel[-hps.hidden_dim:]

    a, b, c, d = tf.split(tf1_bias, num_or_size_splits=4, axis=0)
    bias = tf.concat(values=[a, c + float(forget_bias), b, d], axis=0)  # + 1 to account for forget bias

    return kernel, recurrent_kernel, bias
```

And two differences I've found that need to be accounted for during use:

1. The activation function in `tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell` is sigmoid but `tf.keras.LSTMCell` is hard sigmoid so this needs to be set on initialization with `activation="sigmoid"`.
2. The states are returned in opposite orders.

```py
output, (c_state_new, m_state_new) = tf.compat.v1.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(hidden_size, state_is_tuple=True)(input, (c_state, m_state))
```

becomes

```py
output, (h_state_new, c_state_new) = tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(hidden_size, activation="sigmoid")(input, (h_state, c_state))
```

where the hidden state is referred to by `m` in rnn_cell and `h` in keras.

Answer (score 1):

You can split the matrix:

If you see [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/93dd14dce2e8751bcaab0a0eb363d55eb0cc5813/tensorflow/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L1070), kernel matrix of TF1 has shape of `(input_shape[-1], self.units)`.

Let's say you have 20 inputs and 128 nodes in an LSTM layer

```
input_units=20
layer_size = 128
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, input_units])
lstm_layers = [tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(layer_size),     tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(layer_size)]
stacked = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell(lstm_layers)
output, state = tf.nn.dynamic_rnn(stacked, input_placeholder, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Your trainable parameters will have these shapes:

```
[<tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(148, 512) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/kernel:0' shape=(256, 512) dtype=float32_ref>,
 <tf.Variable 'rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_1/lstm_cell/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32_ref>]
```

In TF 1.0, kernel and recurrent kernel of TF 2.0 is concatenated (see [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/RNN))

```
def build(self, input_shape):
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=(input_shape[-1], self.units),
                              initializer='uniform',
                              name='kernel')
   self.recurrent_kernel = self.add_weight(
    shape=(self.units, self.units),
    initializer='uniform',
    name='recurrent_kernel')
    self.built = True
```

At this new version you have now two different weight matrices.

```
input_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, input_units])
lstm_layers = [tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(layer_size),tf.keras.layers.LSTMCell(layer_size)]
stacked = tf.keras.layers.StackedRNNCells(lstm_layers)
output = tf.keras.layers.RNN(stacked, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Thus, your trainable parameters are:

```
<tf.Variable 'rnn_1/while/stacked_rnn_cells_1/kernel:0' shape=(20, 512) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'rnn_1/while/stacked_rnn_cells_1/recurrent_kernel:0' shape=(128, 512) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'rnn_1/while/stacked_rnn_cells_1/bias:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'rnn_1/while/stacked_rnn_cells_1/kernel_1:0' shape=(128, 512) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'rnn_1/while/stacked_rnn_cells_1/recurrent_kernel_1:0' shape=(128, 512) dtype=float32>,
<tf.Variable 'rnn_1/while/stacked_rnn_cells_1/bias_1:0' shape=(512,) dtype=float32>]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm aware the old kernel is concatenated, however after undoing the concatenation, I do not get the same results.

Comment: what you mean you cannot get the same results? the same of what?

Comment: I'm converting old code. The output of the rnn is different.